# How to optimize my web app's video for screen sharing?

Tags: google-chrome, video-streaming, html5-video, screen-resolution, screensharing

I'm creating a web app that is going to include a video.
Users are going to open my app in a new Chrome window, and screen share it via Zoom.
The video will never be in full screen mode, but it will fill up the whole window.

How can I optimize the video/window resolution for screen sharing so that the video quality will be the highest possible for viewers on Zoom?
Is it possible to make it optimal while keeping a small window size or do they have to use a large window size for the screen sharing to be high quality?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

When sharing a window, only the rasterized pixel output of that window is captured.

Therefore, if you need a high resolution version of your web page, the window that is opened must also be sized appropriately.

Additionally, video is particularly tricky because capturing video from a window requires a great deal of CPU and isn't normally done at full frame rate.  Codecs used with screen sharing are optimized for a low frame rate, higher resolution, and quality.  Because of these limitations, you are basically never going to get a good quality video shared from a web page to stream correctly over Zoom or any similar software.

You'll have to either make-do with the quality that exists now, or you'll have to skip the screen-sharing route entirely.

Comment: I researched and found a lot of video conference (like Whereby) and streaming apps (like BeLive, StreamYard, ReStream) that are web based which are using the WebRTC screen capture. I wonder if they are doing any optimizations on the client side or server side to achieve a good quality stream.

Comment: @amiregelz They don't have access to anything more than you do.  The browser is what actually does the capture.  Chrome is able to capture shared tabs better, but that's about it.  Sharing a whole screen is different.